# Cannot restart mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to restart my mongodb but it has an error

this is the error:

```
[root@testdb vagrant]# sudo service mongod restart
Stopping mongod:                                           [FAILED]
Starting mongod: warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 6843
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
                                                           [FAILED]
```

my config file is:

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
dbpath = /var/lib/mongodb
fork = true
logappend = true
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
nojournal = false
pidfilepath = /var/run/mongodb/mongodb.pid
port = 27017
rest = false
smallfiles = false
```

this is my log

[image]

this is the output of `ps ax | grep mongod`

```
1935 ?        Sl     1:53 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
5592 pts/0    S+     0:00 tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
5889 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep mongod
```

i also removed `/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`

when i restart this is the output stop failed.

```
Stopping mongod:                                           [FAILED]
Starting mongod: warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 5874
child process started successfully, parent exiting
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

Comment: whats your log file say? should be located here /var/log/mongo/mongod.log

Comment: hello @NooBskie i uploaded my log

Comment: can you see if any other isntances are running `ps ax | grep mongod` and post the output

Comment: Also you can try removing the lock manually `sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock` also make sure mongo owns the directorys with `chown-R mongod: mongod /var/lib/mongo`

Comment: uhm. . when i try to stop it failed. . but when i start its ok

Comment: I added the ansswer to your question accept if it helped please:) the only reason it failed on restart is because the process was never started in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely either a permissions issue or a incorrect shutdown.

Run commands `sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock` to remove the lock on mongod process then chown the directory to the mongod user using

`chown-R mongod: mongod /var/lib/mongo`
then start service `sudo service mongod start`

Answer (score 0):

Before I try and give my input, here is the MongoDB documentation for processes:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#StartingandStoppingMongo-SendingshutdownServer%28%29messagefromthemongoshell

That being said, trying shutting down the server:

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

and starting it again.

If you're using linux:

```
mongod --shutdown
```

I hope this helped a little, or atleast you can try and use the documentation.